# Client can't connect to websocket server using servers ip

Tags: python, websocket, server, raspberry-pi, client

I'm building a home automation project, I have a websocket server I've built with pythons websocket and asyncio libraries. When I use a python client testing script and use local host to connect, it works perfectly. However, when I use my computers IPv4 address it doesn't. I've tried connecting using esp's, raspberry pi's and the same testing script on the same computer. Any idea's?

Comment: This means the server is not reachable outside of local-host. Since it's working in local-host, the problem is not in the code.

Maybe the firewall of your computer is blocking the port? Try switching to another port.

Comment: Also what OS are you running this on?

Comment: I did a little bit of searching, this answer can give you more insights
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410435/connect-websocket-server-by-lan-ip-address

Comment: I actually figured out that it was the firewall right after I posted this