# Problem with website making a websocket connection to another web server

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

I have a regular html/javascript website. Then another webserver hosted in python. I am trying to establish a websocket connection between them. The javascript websocket as the client connected to a websocket server on the python webserver.

The end goal is to run the javascript website on my computer and the python webserver on a raspberry pi. For testing purposes I am running both on my computer. When websocketing to "ws://localhost:8070" (8070 being the port of the python webserver) it works fine. But to "ws://192.168.10.170:8070" (ip of raspberry pi). It doesn't. I just get Websocket connection to failed, then WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.
I have tried running both on my computer and using the ip of that same computer instead of localhost, but that doesn't work either. I've tried running the python webserver on my raspberry and trying to connect using pie socket test extension to the raspberry pies ip. That doesn't work either.

TLDR: It works when typing localhost:8070 and 127.0.0.1:8070, but not with any other ips. Even the typed out version of localhost in this case 192.168.10.152 (which is my computer)

EDIT: All firewall rules and such are set.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410435/connect-websocket-server-by-lan-ip-address This might help

Comment: You need to provide a bit more info on your websocket server running on python - which version and what you are using to launch it. The  main reason why this would not work is because you are launching your websocket server and bidding it to localhost (probably by default) and not to the IP that you want to use. Therefore, if you use the IP it fails. Check the default parameters of starting your websocket - please also provide the library and code that you are using through a small snippet - that will help to get an answer.